# Telemetry and advanced logging for c# program

Tags: .net, logging, monitoring

Sometimes I have following troubles during developing applications:

1. The app works fine in my test environment but when I put it on production it has defects on some kind of data and it is hard to figure out which data lead to the defect.
2. I would like to monitor performance of my app in real time, it is not only because I want to optimize it but because I want just ensure that everything is fine and perfromance didn't falling down because of some queue with packets, a lot of threads, memory leaks or something.
3. Sometimes I have a deal with legacy code and it is hard to understand how does it work, what is code flow etc. So I would like to see code flow and method parameters.

I know about tracers, profilers and so on, but only a few of them log parameters and I really want to analysis my code by myself. So I want to write linq queries, create charts and so on for specific parameters or for code flow.

For example, I would like to know which parameters makes method slow working or lead to exception.

Basically I want the software which intercept all method calls with parameters and put it in log file or transfer by network and give me ability to analysis all code flow.

I know that it might reduce performance a lot but for some type of software it is not critical (for example for most web applications the only slow point is database the rest works just very quick)

Also for sure I can write everything by hand but it is very routine especially for big amount of applications.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted but people usually expect to see at least 1 made attempt (by providing a brief code). Perhaps that's the reason.

Comment: In my case it is hard to provide any code cause I'm asking about the tool or solution. I tried to google but with no luck, actually I'm thinking about creating such tool but want to ensure that it is not reinventing the wheel.